# PHP pdo ODBC and mdb file driver

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo, odbc

I have PHP 5.5 on Windows 7 [ampps](/questions/tagged/ampps). I'm trying to access an MS Access data base file named `main.mdb` using PHP. I'm using the following code:

```
<?php
$dbName = "C:\\test\\main.mdb";
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
}
// The following is line 7
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};charset=UTF-8; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
//$db->exec("set names windows-1256");
$sql = "SELECT 0bok.*, `0cat`.name FROM 0bok INNER JOIN 0cat ON `0cat`.id = `0bok`.cat WHERE cat = 35 OR cat = 38 OR cat = 39 OR cat = 41 OR cat = 47 OR cat = 48 OR cat = 4 OR cat = 5 ORDER BY cat";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetchAll();
$i = 1;

echo "<pre>";
foreach ($row as $book) {
    echo $i . ": " . iconv("windows-1256", "utf-8", $book['bk']) . ", " . $book['bkid'] . " -> " . iconv("windows-1256", "utf-8", $book['name'])  . "\n";
    $i++;
}
```

However, I have got the following error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not
>   find driver' in C:\some\path\di.php:7 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\some\path\di.php(7): PDO->__construct('odbc:DRIVER={Mi...') #1
>   {main} thrown in C:\some\path\di.php on line 7

The question is: How could I got the missed driver and make it works with the code that I have regarded above?

Comment: Check your php.ini file to see if the `extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll` line is commented out. If it is, remove the leading semicolon and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO supports a number of different drivers but not all of them are enabled by default. For PDO_ODBC on Windows we need to ensure that the line

```
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
```

is enabled (not commented out) in php.ini.